# Wakeup after suspend reboots IdeaPad 5 14ALC05 under Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: suspend, acpi, ideapad

I have just purchased a new IdeaPad 5 14ALC05 w/o OS and installed Ubuntu 21.04. So far so good.

The problem is that suspend appears not to work. No matter wether the power cord is connected or not, when I close the lid and wait for ca. 20 s or when I use the desktop menu / Power Off / Suspend function, the screen turns black and the power LED starts slowly pulsing, so I take it the system is suspended.

When I wake up the notebook by hitting the space bar or opening the lid, I end up in the GRUB menu -- apparently, the systen was rebooted.

```
BIOS: G5CN16WW V1.04 (latest version)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics
RAM: 8GB
SSD: 256 GB
/sys/power/disk: [disabled]
/sys/power/mem_sleep: [s2idle]
/sys/power/state: freeze mem
/sys/power/suspend_stats/*: all counters are 0
dmesg |grep ACPI |grep supports: S0 S4 S5
```

I tried to follow [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_14are05#Suspend_issues_(S3_sleep_fix)) for (what I think is) a similar system, IdeaPad 5 14ARE05, but I do not get the message that ACPI supports S3.

Can someone please help and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found your post also on the [Lenovo forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/view/2713/5083252), but let me answer here as well.

I have the same notebook, and was able to put the notebook to sleep by updating the kernel to the latest version 5.13. One step forward, two steps back - the notebook goes to sleep correctly, but waking up does not turn on the screen. The notebook is still accessible via SSH though, so it's not a full lock-up, just some issue with the GPU driver I imagine. For now I was not able figure out how to fix this issue.